# PHP Laravel - Finding the quantity of seconds in each hour between two timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, time, hour, seconds

I'm trying to track the time someone is spent logged onto a system. I need to be able to group the total seconds spent logged in into hours. A user might have a logged on and logged off event that will span across multiple hours but I need to ensure that correct amount of seconds are logged against the correct hour.

For example, if a user were to log on a 17:55 and log off at 18:10 the user would have 300 seconds in hour 17:00 and 600 seconds in hour 18:00

I have searched absolutely everywhere and cannot find a solution that doesn't involve a cumbersome while loop, I'm working with a large data set so it must be efficient.

If anyone has come across this problem before or has any ideas that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is too broad to be answered properly, but you will (almost) always have just 2 instances of hours with less than an hour of time. At the beginning and end of the session. So just calculate difference between: start time and start of previous hour, end of next hour and stop time.

Answer (score 0):

So another performant approach would be using raw SQL.
I'm supposing you are using a table named user_sessions or so.

```
$results = DB::table('user_sessions')
    ->select(DB::raw('HOUR(login_time) AS hour,    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(logout_time, login_time))) AS seconds'))->whereTime('login_time', '>=', $loginTime)
    ->whereTime('logout_time', '<=', $logoutTime)
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('HOUR(login_time)'))
    ->get();

$formattedResults = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $formattedResults[] = [
        'hour' => $result->hour,
        'seconds' => $result->seconds,
    ];
}

return json_encode($formattedResults);
```

I hope this helps. Or at least gives you an idea .

Comment: These $login_time $logout_time i have supposed that are variables that u already have or remove them for making a scan in the whole table. I added them for example to make query for a certain timespan such a daily or else.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a log file, so WRITE to this file when a user logs in or out and print the timestamp in that exact moment.

Then you would query by reading in this file and group by that criteria, by creating a date diff in seconds.

More concrete information would be valuable.

Comment: Hi, sorry If I was unclear in my question. I am already storing the logon and logoff events in a database. I have actually already done some pre-processing so I have a pair of logon and logoff events on a single row in my database. I.e. my data is stored like this: user_id, on_time, off_time. I now need to calculate the proper amount in seconds that a user is logged in for grouped by hour. The array needs to be formatted in this way: [{"hour"; "17", "seconds": 300},{"hour": "18", "seconds": 600]

Comment: Ok now its clear. What i would suggest woud be this: Use SQL to have a more performant solution. I will give you a small example in another answer here below.